# Linq to SQL - a query to get a count() even when 0

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have this query:

```
(from a in SickDays
    join b in Class.Where(p => p.ID == myId) on a.Class_ID equals b.ID
    join c in Student on a.Student_ID equals c.ID
    group a by new { c.Name, c.Order } into ac
    select new { Count = ac.Count(), Name = ac.Key.Name, Order = ac.Key.Order }
).OrderBy(f => f.Order)
```

This returns:

```
Count | Name | Order
    3 | Dave |     a
    2 | John |     b
    7 | Sally|     c
```

However I'd like it to return this:

```
Count | Name | Order
    3 | Dave |     a
    2 | John |     b
    7 | Sally|     c
    0 | Mark |     d
    0 | Betty|     e
```

**UPDATE:**
This is what Students, Classes and SickDays look like using @sixlettervariables example:

```
var Students = new List<Student>()
{
    new Student { Id = 1, Name = "Al", Order = 'a' },
    new Student { Id = 2, Name = "Betty", Order = 'b' },
    new Student { Id = 3, Name = "Charles", Order = 'c' },
};

var Classes = new List<Class>()
{
    new Class { Id = 1, Title = "A100" },
    new Class { Id = 2, Title = "A200" },
};

var SickDays = new List<SickDay>()
{
    new SickDay { Id = 1, StudentId = 1, ClassId = 1 },
    new SickDay { Id = 2, StudentId = 1, ClassId = 1 },
    new SickDay { Id = 3, StudentId = 1, ClassId = 2 },
    new SickDay { Id = 4, StudentId = 1, ClassId = 2 },
    new SickDay { Id = 5, StudentId = 2, ClassId = 1 },
};
```

Ok the above is now correct, so sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Wait! I've confused myself with the 'Update'. I've used Students, Classes and SickDays as an example, but my application uses different objects - bare with me a few minutes while I sort out precisely what Students, Classes and SickDays look like.

Comment: Ok now it's correct...again I'm really sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as a [Left Outer Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx). In this case, every *Student* is required even if they have no *Sick Days*. So, we would start with the students, perform a left outer join with the sick days, and then return the count of the classes which matched the ID you had specified:

```
var query =
    from s in Students
    join d in SickDays on s.ID equals d.Student_ID into gj
    from sd in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group sd by new { s.Name, s.Order } into gg
    select
        new
        {
            Name = gg.Key.Name,
            Order = gg.Key.Order,
            Count = gg.Count(x => x != null && x.Class_ID == myId)
        };
```

Comment: [This works, assuming I understood what was being counted.](http://ideone.com/p12ts)

Comment: Just to let you know, @sixlettervariables, I'm still testing your solution

Comment: You champion, it works! Even when I was confused over my own question you understood it :-) Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome, you could extend this approach to see exactly which classes each student missed by swapping `Count` out for `Missed = gg.ToArray()` and then using `Missed.Count()` instead in code.

Answer (score 0):

So you want all the students even if they aren't in the class?  Then you need a left join I believe.  with Linq this is achieved using DefaultIfEmpty()

Try this?

```
(from a in SickDays
    join b in Class.Where(p => p.ID == myId) on a.Class_ID equals b.ID
    join c in Student on a.Student_ID equals c.ID
        into s
    from students in s.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group a by new { students.Name, students.Order } into ac
    select new { Count = ac.Count(), Name = ac.Key.Name, Order = ac.Key.Order }
).OrderBy(f => f.Order)
```

I hope that gets you in the right direction.

Comment: It's not the student that is missing, but rather the sick day.